# Method not allowed in WCF Rest service

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "createinvoice", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Invoice CreateInvoice(string instance)
    {
        // TODO: Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection
        try
        {

            string icode = instance;
            //decimal paid = instance.AmountPaid;

            return new Invoice() {InvoiceCode = icode };
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Everytime i run it on the browser it says:

```
Method not allowed. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
```

Any ideas? Also when i go and do this on the browser.  it says Endpoint not found. (Mobile) is a virtual directory while (POS) is a registered route for service1.cs

Answer (score 0):

Posting to the URL from browser will not work. You need your custom code or use fiddler(use Composer and select POST) [Another link with solution.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/33412475-2484-49e3-8360-c80197fac591)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is under *"Everytime i run it on the browser it says:"* 
Your web browser request is a GET request .You can change `WebInvoke` to `WebGet` and remove POST Method attribute or build a POST request using a tool.